# Change x-axis labeling independent of x values

Tags: r

I have a problem with the x-axis labelling.

I created a *lm* model(first.stage) and plotted the residuals using the code:

```
plot(first.stage$residuals,ylab="Deviation",xlab="Year",type="l",col="blue")
```

Now I'd like to change the x-axis labelling independent from the *x* values.

More precisely, I want to show the years 1960-2010 on the *x* axis. I tried a lot nothing worked.

Comment: Do you want to change the label on the x axis? or do you want to change the range of dates displayed on the x axis?

Comment: Maybe use xlim, e.g.: `plot(3:5, xlim = c(1, 4))`

Comment: if your try to provide a reproductible example it is easier to help you. Posting what you tried can help too.

Comment: sorry, not the label, that is just called "Years". I just want a range 1960,1970...2010...on the x-axis...but independent from the actuall x values.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set custom tick marks for your x axis, set `xaxt = 'n'` in the `plot()` call, then use `axis(1, at = c())` to set the new tick marks. For example,

```
plot(mtcars$wt, mtcars$mpg, xaxt='n')
axis(1, at = c(1.5, 2.5))
```

Comment: Thanks! I've already tried this. But I don't want to change the tick marks...I'd just like to plot the residuals of my model, which should display the deviations from an Index for the years 1960-2010. Its hard to get more precise as I can't upload the graph for any reason...Its just changing the "labeling" of the tick marks

Comment: Have you tried creating another variable containing the years (e.g. `yrs <- 1960:2010`), then plotting that new variable on the x-axis with residuals on the y-axis?

Comment: Yes, I tried that too. But then I got different lengths of the variables and it doesn't work either. I thought there is a way to JUST name the tick marks "manually"...It works when I create  time series, but I can't estimate my model with ts...